# Backbone.js model.save() fire a "too much recursion" error in underscore

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a problem trying to use backbone on saving my Model from a form. Here I want my my view to actually be an editing form:

```
    (function() {

    'use strict';

    var YachtEditor = {};
    window.YachtEditor = YachtEditor;

    var template = function(name) {
        return Mustache.compile($('#' + name + 'Template').html());
    };

    YachtEditor.Tank = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            dCapacity : "",
            sType : ""
        }
    });

    YachtEditor.Tanks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //      url: "/rest/tanks",
        localStorage: new Store("tanks"),
        model : YachtEditor.Tank
    });

    YachtEditor.TankView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: template("tank"),
        events: {
            'click .save' : 'save',
            'click .remove' : 'remove'
        },
        initialize: function() {
            console.log("initialize tank View :");
            console.log(this.model.get("id"));
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this));
            return this;
        },
        save: function() {
            console.log('change');

            var self = this;
            var values = {
                    sType:     self.$("#sType").val(),
                    dCapacity: self.$("#dCapacity").val()
                };

            console.log("dCapacity : " + values.dCapacity);
            console.log("sType : " + values.sType);

            this.model.save(values);
        },
        remove: function() {
            this.model.destroy();
        },
        dCapacity : function() {
            return this.model.get("dCapacity");
        },
        sType : function() {
            return this.model.get("sType");
        }
    });

    YachtEditor.TanksView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("div.tankZone"),
        template: template("tanks"),
        events: {
            "click .add" : "addTank",
            "click .clear" : "clear"
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.tanks = new YachtEditor.Tanks();
//          this.tanks.on('all', this.render, this);
            this.tanks.fetch();
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this));
            this.tanks.each(this.renderTank, this);
            return this;
        },
        renderTank: function(tank) {
            var view = new YachtEditor.TankView({model: tank});
            $(".tanks").append(view.render().el);
            return this;
        },
        addTank: function() {
            this.tanks.create({});
            this.render();
        },
        clear: function() {
            this.tanks.each(function(tank) {
                tank.destroy();
            });
            this.render();
        }
    });
    ...
    })();
```

Here is the mustache template i use for each tank

```
<script id="tankTemplate" type="text/x-mustache-template">      
    <div class="tankView">
        <h1>Tank</h1>
        <select id="sType" value="{{ sType }}">
            @for(option <- Tank.Type.values().toList) {
                <option>@option.toString</option>
            }
        </select> 
        <input id="dCapacity" type="text" value="{{ dCapacity }}">
        <button class="destroy">x</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

My problem here is that this.model.save() triggers a 'too much recursion' in underscore. js. (chrome is displaying an error also.

Here is the call stack on error:

```
_.extend
_.clone
_.extend.toJSON
_.extend.save
_.extend.update
Backbone.sync
_.extend.sync
_.extend.save
YachtEditor.TankView.Backbone.View.extend.save
st.event.dispatch
y.handle
```

I suspect the save to recall the blur event but i cannot find a way to explicit it... Maybe I'm not using backbone as i should?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, could you the error stack trace so that we can know which method is recursively called?

Comment: I updated the post to let you see the error call stack

Answer (score 1):

My problem, aside of some pointed out by Yurui Ray Zhang (thank you), was that I was using a backbone-localstorage.js from an example I found here : git://github.com/ngauthier/intro-to-backbone-js.git

The "too much recursion error" stopped to appear as soon a I replaced it with a storage I found here : https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

Answer (score 0):

a few things. you defined your tank model as

```
app.Tank = ...
```

but in your collection you are referencing it as:

```
model : YachtEditor.Tank
```

and in your view, you are trying to assign elements before they are rendered on the page:

```
this.input = {}
this.input.sType     = this.$("#sType");
this.input.dCapacity = this.$("#dCapacity");
```

I'm not sure how your view is rendered to the page, some people, like me, like to use render() to render the template directly to the page:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this));
   //done, you should be able to see the form on the page now.
},
```

some others, will use something else to insert the el, eg:

```
//in another view
tankView.render().$el.appendTo('body');
```

but either way, if you want to cache your elements, you need to do it after they are rendered to the page, not in initialize.

```
//this method is only called after render() is called! 
cacheElements: function() {
    this.input = {}
    this.input.sType     = this.$("#sType");
    this.input.dCapacity = this.$("#dCapacity");
}
```

I'd suggest, first, try to fix this things, and then, try to add some console log or debuggers in your readForm method to see if the values are grabbed correctly:

```
readForm: function() {
    var input = this.input;
    console.log(input.sType.val());
    console.log(input.dCapacity.val());
    this.model.save({
        sType:     input.sType.val(),
        dCapacity: input.dCapacity.val()
    });
},
```

Comment: Ok so I corrected my bad refactoring and suppressed the elements caching. I also added a save button in the Tank template to eliminate any event recursion suspicion. I'll edit my question to update everything. I'll also add the code of the Motherview (the one managing the list)

Comment: so do you see correct values in the console log? also can you just try to create a model in your console and try save it?

Comment: yes, i can actually see the right values, but model.save still give me an error... Some times save() returns, but call it again and it will throw an error. Also: the localStorage is not updated

Comment: hm...i haven't used localstorage for backbone before, not sure if it related to localstorage configuration or something. I'd try to recreate the error in the console (without using views) to see if localstorage is working with your model/collection configuration.